# The intersection of 2 CFL

Tags: formal-languages, context-free

I have the following two CFL: $A =\{a^m b^n c^n\}$ and $B = \{a^m b^m c^n\}$.
I don't understand why the intersection of this languages is $\{a^n b^n c^n\}$: can anyone explain to me why the power is to the $n$ and not to the $m$ or something else?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: (My guess: no. The point is all *exponents being equal*, not how they are designated. It may have been unfortunate to use non-distinct sets of labels for the three languages in the first place, but with the choice as shown, $m$ would have been just as valid as $n$ - a matter of habit.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The set $A$ cointains all the strings on the alphabet $\{a,b,c\}$ starting with $a$, ending with $c$ and with the same number of $b$s and $c$s. Similarly, $B$ is made by strings on the same alphabet, starting with $a$, ending with $c$ and with the same number of $a$s and $b$s.

So the intersection $A\cap B$ simply cointains all the strings on the alphabet $\{a,b,c\}$ starting with $a$, ending with $c$, with the same number of $b$s and $c$s and the same number of $a$s and $b$s. By the transitivity of equality (I mean, if $x=y$ and $y=z$ then $x=z$, where $x$, $y$ and $z$ are the numbers of $b$s, $c$s and $a$s in a string), you can express these last two condition by saying that the number of $a$s, $b$s and $c$s is the same, *i.e.*, that the strings in $A\cap B$ are of the form $a^n b^n c^n$ for some natural number $n$ (of course here you can use the letter $m$, or any other letter you prefer, instead of $n$).

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

You have that $A=\{a^mb^nc^n:\ m,n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ and $B=\{a^mb^mc^n:\ m,n\in\mathbb{N}\}$. If $w\in A$, then there are $r,s\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $w=a^rb^sc^s$. If we also have that $w\in B$ (such that $w\in A\cap B$), then there are $t,u\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $w=a^tb^tc^u$.

Therefore, $a^rb^sc^s=w=a^tb^tc^u$.

> We need to assume that $a,b,c$ are different characters. Otherwise the conclusion wanted is not satisfied. For example, if $a=b=c$, then $A=B=\{a^n:\ n\in\mathbb{N}\}$, while $A\cap B= A\neq\{a^na^na^n:\ n\in\mathbb{N}\}$. This assumption, if it was not explicitly said, it was probably intended.

Now, if $r<t$ (or $r>t$), then comparing the $(r+1)$-th (or $(t+1)$-th) letters of $a^rb^sc^s$ and $a^tb^tc^u$ we would get $a=b$. This is a contradiction. Therefore, $r=t$.

So, $a^rb^sc^s=a^rb^sc^s=w=a^tb^tc^u=a^rb^rc^u$. We do the same analysis with $r$ and $s$. If $r<s$ (or $r>s$) we compare the $(r+1)$-th (or $(s+1)$-th) characters of $a^rb^sc^s$ and $a^rb^rc^u$. This gives that $b=c$, which is a contradiction. Therefore, $r=s$.

So, $a^rb^rc^r=w$.

Comment: Thank you so much.